# Change values of Cells in a Filtered DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, datagridview

I have DataGridView with a Column named `flag` and others.
When I apply a filter:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = 
    new DataView(ds, "flag = 1", "tw_Name DESC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

it shows only Rows where he Column `flag` value is equal to 1, but...
when I try to programmatically change this value, for example in 6 checked rows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["zazn"].Value))
    {
        row.Cells["flags"].Value = 0;
    }
}
```

three Rows disappear, one Row changes its value, two Rows do not change.
Next, when I click any Row, I get only 2 of the desired changes.

Comment: Are you resetting the DataSource to apply a filter? -- It looks like your DGV DataSource is a DataTable, then, to apply a filter and sort: `var dv = (dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView; dv.RowFilter = "flag = 1"; dv.Sort = "tw_Name DESC";`

Comment: Yes, DataSource is a DataTable. I apply a filter and sort like Jimi writed but problem is the same

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with a DataTable, it's preferable that you modify the values of its Rows' content instead the DataGridView Cells while a Filter is active on the DataTable's DataView.

This causes the immediate propagation of the data changes, which your DataGridView will acknowledge. Not guaranteed if you do the opposite, trying to propagate the Control's changes to the DataSource.
This may go against the internal mechanics used by the Control to notify the changes to its DataSource: a DataGridView notify value changes of its Cells after the Cell edit has completed and validation has been performed.

You could try to call `[DataGridView].EndEdit()` and `Validate()`, it doesn't mean that in any circumstance the Control and the DataSource will synchronize when you expect it to happen.

---

Set the Filter and order the View:

- Note that the order is applied to the DefaultView, not the DataTable. The Rows' order in the DataTable remains unchanged.

<sub>*In your sample code, a filter is set to `flag = 1`, while you use another name for the Column in `row.Cells["flags"]`.*</sub>

```
var dView = (dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView;
dView.RowFilter = "flag = 1";
dView.Sort = "tw_Name DESC";
```

When you need to change values in some of the Rows, access the DataTable using the `DataGridView.DataSource` and cast it to `DataTable` (or BindingSouce or whatever other source of data you have used).
You can now loop the DataRows and set new values to some Columns base on a condition, as in this case:

```
var dt = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    var row = dt.Rows[i];
    if (row["zazn"] != DBNull.Value && (bool)row["zazn"]) {
        row["flag"] = 0;
    }
}
```

You *could* do the same thing using the [DataGridView.Row.DataBoundItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem), which is a DataRowView in this case, looping backwards (to only loop the visible Rows):

```
var dt = dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable;

//BACKWARDS - also assuming there's a NewRow, so Rows.Count - 2
for (int i = dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = (dataGridView2.Rows[i].DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
    if (row["zazn"] != DBNull.Value && (bool)row["zazn"]) {
        row["flag"] = 0;
    }
}
```

If you do the same but with a forward loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; i++) { ... }
```

you're in the same situation as before.